# How to export members of opened module in Dafny?

Tags: dafny

I can't get the following example to pass resolution in Dafny:

```
module A{
  export all reveals *
  export provides P // I don't want to reveal the implementation of P by default
  type P<!T(==)> = iset<T>
}

module B{
  import opened A`all
  export provides Test

  function Test(): P<nat>
}
```

Basically, I would like the function `Test()` to be provided by default from B and the type `P` to also be provided, not revealed.
I can't find in the documentation how to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to say more in the export set of `B`. Here's a way you can do it:

```
module A{
  export all
    reveals *
  export
    provides P // I don't want to reveal the implementation of P by default

  type P<!T(==)> = iset<T>
}

module B {
  export
    provides Test, JustP

  import JustP = A
  import opened Everything = A`all

  function Test(): P<nat> {
    iset{} // module B knows what P is, because it imports A`all
  }
}

module Client {
  import B

  method M() {
    var p: B.JustP.P<nat>; // Client can use P, but only as an opaque type
    p := iset{}; // error: Client does not know what P is
  }
}
```

You can also change

```
  import opened Everything = A`all
```

to just

```
  import Everything = A`all
```

if you also change the signature of `B.Test` to

```
function Test(): Everything.P<nat>
```

But, for reasons I don't understand, if you change the "everything" import declaration to

```
  import opened A`all
```

then you don't get the desired effect of hiding the definition of `P` from `Client` (this may be a bug).